# Is it possible to adjust the sound volume cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I am using the following method, and express a sound effect in cocos2d.

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"BackGround.m4a"];
```

But sound volume of BackgroundMusic is too small.

so, is there a way that adjust a sound volume?

Comment: Btw, I seperated the CocosDenshion API reference from the Cocos2D API reference, makes it much easier to look up CocosDenshion-specific classes:
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/CocosDenshion/html/interface_simple_audio_engine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [backgroundMusicVolume](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_simple_audio_engine.html#a7e28cfae58e49d3b6dd4a1ca9b8b54b5) property of the SimpleAudioEngine class can be used for this.

```
- (float) backgroundMusicVolume [read, write, assign]

   //Background music volume. Range is 0.0f to 1.0f. This will only have an effect if willPlayBackgroundMusic returns YES
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]setBackgroundMusicVolume:1.0f];
```

From 0.0f to 1.0f.