# Sound slider for cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

Any tutorials on how to make a slider for cocos2d that controls sounds that you guys recommend? Some of tutorials look a bit shady.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the slider provides by the [CCControlExtension](https://github.com/YannickL/CCControlExtension) and use the callback method to change the volume of your sound as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344845/is-it-possible-to-adjust-the-sound-volume-cocos2d).

Here a "pseudo" code to show you how to achieved this:

```
// Create your audio engine
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"music.mp3"];

// Create the slider
CCControlSlider *slider = [CCControlSlider sliderWithBackgroundFile:@"sliderTrack.png" progressFile:@"sliderProgress.png" thumbFile:@"sliderThumb.png"];
slider.minimumValue = 0.0f; // Sets the min value of range
slider.maximumValue = 1.0f; // Sets the max value of range

// When the value of the slider will change, the given selector will be call
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:CCControlEventValueChanged];

[self addChild:slider]; 

//...

- (void)valueChanged:(CCControlSlider *)sender
{
   // Change volume of your sounds
   [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:sender.value];
   [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setBackgroundMusicVolume:sender.value];
}
```

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, any suggestions for putting it in a certain location? I was thinking about using rect, but don't know if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: What do you mean by location? To position it you just have to use the slider.position attribute.